# Single SQL query to retrieve data in a particular order (not ASC/DESC)

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a MySQL table called **reviews**

```
review_id, product_id, language_id, rating, review, author
```

**language_id** ranges from **1 to 10** for 10 different languages.

Let's say I determine that my visitor is browsing the site using language whose id is 4

Is there a way to write a single query that:
1. First grabs the reviews for that product in current language 
2. Next, grabs the reviews for that product in other languages sorted by language

So, basically does the job of the following 2 queries run one after the other:

```
SELECT * FROM reviews WHERE product_id = 723 AND language_id = 4;
SELECT * FROM reviews WHERE product_id = 723 AND language_id != 4 ORDER BY language_id ASC;
```

Comment: I suppose UNION would combine the two queries. But wouldn't the performance still be kindof low i.e. equivalent of 2 queries? I suppose my objective is to access the table only once since both queries run on the same table.

Comment: So, reorder on a server side.

Comment: Sorry for being such a noob, but I don't know what that means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM reviews WHERE product_id = 723
order by case when language_id = 4 then 0 else 1 end, language_id;
```

Comment: Thanks! This looks promising. Will try out and then accept answer. In the meantime, where can I read about order by case apart from http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html which is a bit dense for me?

Comment: @OC2PS You're welcome. Link you posted has enough information. Think of CASE-WHEN-ELSE-END as of any other scalar function, but with specific syntax. For example SUBSTRING. You can use CASE everywhere where you can use these functions

Comment: Nice, you have opened up a whole new world for me :-)

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM reviews WHERE product_id = 723 AND language_id = 4

UNION 
SELECT * FROM reviews WHERE product_id = 723 AND language_id != 4 ORDER BY language_id ASC;
```

**Explanation:**

Your requirement is pretty simple.

You have two SQLs and you want a combined outout.

As the table is same also, the fields, use [MySQL UNION](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html).